# Please reopen question: Everyone Behave Rude and Don't Listen to Me

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I am asking for this question to be re - opened.

[Addressing dev team's resistance to solutions suggested by QA engineer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/everyone-behave-rude-and-dont-listen-to-me-because-im-working-as-qa)

The OP is frustrated due not to not being taken seriously and his / her ideas ignored. I work in a very similar field - IT Audit / compliance and have several instances similar to the OP.

Comment: It is reopened now.

Comment: Thanks for posting this here. I'm continually encouraged to see how many people are taking ownership and interest in meta!

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, the OP hasn't really asked an answerable question.  It's compounded by this:

> Sorry that I don't have exact question to ask...

There is an edit waiting in the approval queue, but the edit seems to be inviting discussion about *multiple* questions rather than trying to distil down the OP's issue to one single question.

Yes I know that the OP is frustrated, but unless there is a clearly answerable question, then I very much doubt it will be reopened.

Comment: I made a further edit to try to focus it more.